# Why do I run into a deadlock with this Golang code?

Tags: go, deadlock

I am quite new to Golang. I wrote the following code for practice and ran into a run-time error message of a deadlock:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func system(WORKERS int) {
    fromW := make(chan bool)
    toW := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i != WORKERS; i++ {
        go worker(toW, fromW)
    }
    coordinator(WORKERS, fromW, toW)
}

func coordinator(WORKERS int, in, out chan bool) {
    result := true
    for i := 0; i != WORKERS; i++ {
        result =  result && <-in
    }
    for i := 0; i != WORKERS; i++ {
        out <- result
    }
    fmt.Println("%t", result)
}

func worker(in, out chan bool) {
    out <- false
    <-in
}

func main() {
    system(2)
}
```

However, if I swap the operands of && in line 19 to have

```
result =  <-in && result,
```

the code works properly without returning any error messages. How can I explain this behaviour? Am I missing anything here? The OS I use is Windows 10, and the Golang version is 1.8.3.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators), the right operand of `&&` is evaluated conditionally.

This means that `result =  result && <-in` will only evaluate `<-in` if `result` is true. So, the coodrinator reads only one `false` from that channel, and skips reading messages from the other workers. If you switch the operands of `&&` places, then the `<-in` will evaluate every time and the deadlock goes away.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you so much.